# How to align the Contact Form 7 plugin form horizontal?

Tags: wordpress, html, css, contact-form-7

I've been trying for a few hours to find the way to display the contact form input fields horizontally as in the module before the contact form here: http://zohar.mapasystem.co.il/

The idea is to replace the Property Search with my Contact Form 7 shortcode.

Using a `<table>` is not an option, since the theme changes automatically the layout for mobile browsers.

```
<label><span> שם מלא (חובה)</span><br>[text* text-3 30/ class:gg] </label>
<label><span> טלפון (חובה)</span><br>[text* text-648 30/ class:gg] </label>
<label><span> אימייל (חובה)</span><br>[email* email-827 30/ class:gg] </label>
<label><span> תקציב להשקעה</span><br>[text text-214 30/ class:gg] </label>
<label class="lastsub"> [submit class:gg "שלח"] </label>
```

I tried `<div>` with width, float, display:inline, etc, etc, but I think my problem is with HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="separate">
<label><span> שם מלא (חובה)</span></label><br>[text* text-3 30/ class:gg]
</div> 

<div class="separate">
<label><span> טלפון (חובה)</span></label><br>[text* text-648 30/ class:gg]
</div>
```

In CSS file:

```
.separate{float:left;}
```

Comment: Hey there! Welcome to SOF! Remember when using syntax remember to use the syntax highlighting markup.